# Multiple variables on same barplot in R with ifelse col statement

Tags: r, plot

I currently have a matrix of data with size 365x8 (365 days, 8 variables). Each day value represents a true or false value, and for each day, I want to plot a red box if true, and a green box if false.

My goal is to display all 8 columns of the matrix in a barplot. Below is some current code I have.

```
data # matrix with size 365x8
# Plot good vs. bad data
first <- barplot(data, xlab = "# of Days", ylab = "Type of Data",
    col=ifelse(data==TRUE, "red", "green"), beside=FALSE, horiz=TRUE,
    xlim=c(0,365))
print(first)
```

I want the ifelse statement for 'col' to go to each value of each column in 'data' and determine which color each value for each day should be. My problem is that I can only get my barplot to plot the first variable in data (data[,1]), and it repeats this for all eight. Do I need to call barplot multiple times (tried to, didn't work), or call something else entirely? I would post a plot of my current progress, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Let me know if I haven't been clear enough, tried my best to describe what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using `ggplot2` and creating a "heatmap" type plot (with `geom_tile`)? I made an example where `dat` is your data matrix, and all the values were either 0 or 1.

```
ggplot(melt(dat), aes(x=Var2, y=Var1, fill=factor(value))) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('green', 'red'))
```

---

EDIT: You will also need to use `melt` from the `reshape2` package. Here is the data I randomly used, and part of the plot generated:

```
dat <- replicate(8, sample(c(0, 0, 0, 1), 365, replace=T))
ggplot(melt(dat[1:50, ]), aes(x=Var2, y=Var1, fill=factor(value))) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('green', 'red'))
```

[image: Example "heatmap"]

Comment: That's a good solution, but you should add the data you used (even if the OP didn't) and mention you also used `reshape2`.

Comment: Also an easier way to generate the data: `dat <- replicate(8, sample(c(0, 0, 0, 1), 365, replace = T))`

Comment: Ah, I knew there was a much better way to do it, but didn't remember `replicate` returns an array. Edited for simplicity.

Comment: I'm aware of ggplot, but haven't used it yet. I'll give it a go and let you guys know. Thanks!

Comment: When you call melt and insert 'dat', does 'dat' have to be a specific data type? 'dat' goes in as numeric in your example.

Comment: In my example, `dat` was a matrix. Then the output will have columns `Var1` and `Var2` which you will plot as `y` and `x` in the `aes` function. (`melt` also creates a column called `value`, which is what will be used for the `fill` argument)

Comment: Awesome, finally got it to work! I took all 8 observations and made a data frame, then converted to a matrix in melt().

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `heatmap()` in base R. It only works with numeric values, though, so you'll need to convert your TRUE/FALSE values to numbers first. Also, to keep the rows and columns in the same order in the plot as in the matrix, you need to turn off reordering in the call to `heatmap()`. So something like this:

```
data.num <- ifelse(data == TRUE, 1, 0)
heatmap(data.num, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, col = ifelse(z==1, "gray15", "gray85"))
```

Comment: I attempted your method, and it plotted, but it was very messy. Would this have to do with reordering?